# index names on MS Windows not accepted, Linux OK

Tags: windows, elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch cluster running on Linux machines without serious problems. I now want to extend it to MS Windows but hit an issue with the names of the indexes, which are not accepted. The log is quite explicit:

```
[2015-02-18 10:18:39,071][WARN ][common.jna               ] unable to link C library. native methods (mlockall) will be disabled.
[2015-02-18 10:18:39,139][INFO ][node                     ] [lenov272dsy] version[1.4.3], pid[1276], build[36a29a7/2015-02-11T14:23:15Z]
[2015-02-18 10:18:39,139][INFO ][node                     ] [lenov272dsy] initializing ...
[2015-02-18 10:18:39,142][INFO ][plugins                  ] [lenov272dsy] loaded [], sites []
[2015-02-18 10:18:41,920][INFO ][node                     ] [lenov272dsy] initialized
[2015-02-18 10:18:41,920][INFO ][node                     ] [lenov272dsy] starting ...
[2015-02-18 10:18:42,104][INFO ][transport                ] [lenov272dsy] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/10.233.85.45:9300]}
[2015-02-18 10:18:42,111][INFO ][discovery                ] [lenov272dsy] security/6CeEuO01SeaL0kZuezwoSg
[2015-02-18 10:18:45,207][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [lenov272dsy] detected_master [eu3][ZsJ2f1gcQpSOlWriWy19-g][eu3][inet[/10.81.163.112:9300]], added {[eu5][nEUNDAc0S4ytvtntjvgIXA][eu5.security.example.com][inet[/10.81.147.186:9300]],[eu4][--PlaWk9Tl2pF8XSHJulDA][eu4.security.example.com][inet[/10.81.163.129:9300]],[eu3][ZsJ2f1gcQpSOlWriWy19-g][eu3][inet[/10.81.163.112:9300]],}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [[eu3][ZsJ2f1gcQpSOlWriWy19-g][eu3][inet[/10.81.163.112:9300]]])
[2015-02-18 10:18:45,322][INFO ][http                     ] [lenov272dsy] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/10.233.85.45:9200]}
[2015-02-18 10:18:45,323][INFO ][node                     ] [lenov272dsy] started
[2015-02-18 10:18:53,009][WARN ][indices.cluster          ] [lenov272dsy] [nessus_scan_recurrent-internet.2015-01-15t00:00:59+00:00.65731fa3-2635-a330-2a7b-00e3ea775493c5ddb3b88c869b73.getnessuscans.nessus][4] failed to create shard
org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShardCreationException: [nessus_scan_recurrent-internet.2015-01-15t00:00:59+00:00.65731fa3-2635-a330-2a7b-00e3ea775493c5ddb3b88c869b73.getnessuscans.nessus][4] failed to create shard
                at org.elasticsearch.index.service.InternalIndexService.createShard(InternalIndexService.java:360)
                at org.elasticsearch.indices.cluster.IndicesClusterStateService.applyInitializingShard(IndicesClusterStateService.java:678)
                at org.elasticsearch.indices.cluster.IndicesClusterStateService.applyNewOrUpdatedShards(IndicesClusterStateService.java:579)
                at org.elasticsearch.indices.cluster.IndicesClusterStateService.clusterChanged(IndicesClusterStateService.java:185)
                at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask.run(InternalClusterService.java:431)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.runAndClean(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:184)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:154)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
                at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
                at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:428)
                at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
                at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.getCanonicalPath(FSDirectory.java:129)
                at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.<init>(FSDirectory.java:143)
                at org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory.<init>(MMapDirectory.java:132)
                at org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory.<init>(MMapDirectory.java:99)
                at org.elasticsearch.index.store.fs.MmapFsDirectoryService.newFSDirectory(MmapFsDirectoryService.java:45)
                at org.elasticsearch.index.store.fs.FsDirectoryService.build(FsDirectoryService.java:129)
                at org.elasticsearch.index.store.distributor.AbstractDistributor.<init>(AbstractDistributor.java:35)
                at org.elasticsearch.index.store.distributor.LeastUsedDistributor.<init>(LeastUsedDistributor.java:36)
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:54)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:86)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:98)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:52)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:837)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:57)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:45)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:98)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:837)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:57)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:45)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:98)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:52)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:837)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:57)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:45)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder$1.call(InjectorBuilder.java:200)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder$1.call(InjectorBuilder.java:193)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:830)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.loadEagerSingletons(InjectorBuilder.java:193)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.injectDynamically(InjectorBuilder.java:175)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.build(InjectorBuilder.java:110)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.createChildInjector(InjectorImpl.java:131)
                at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ModulesBuilder.createChildInjector(ModulesBuilder.java:69)
                at org.elasticsearch.index.service.InternalIndexService.createShard(InternalIndexService.java:358)
                ... 9 more
```

This is repeated for other similar indexes, the key part being

> `Caused by: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`

I had a look at how indexes are stored on the Linux boxes and there are indeed directories named after them.

Short of renaming the indexes, is there a way to make them compatible with a Windows install of elasticsearch? (I looked at the configuration but did not find anything -- my personal, uninformed and certainly naive opinion is that there should not be such OS dependency and something like a hash of the index name should be used instead)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After side discussions with other users of elasticsearch and further tests, the problem is indeed that the index name must use characters which are correct in a filename for a given OS (indexes are stored in files and folders named after the index name).

It is therefore better to use a safe set of characters, universally accepted among the OSes in filenames (letters, digits, underscore).

Answer (score 0):

May sound silly, but double check that ElasticSearch has sufficient permissions to create things in its installation folder.

Comment: The permissions are correct. I am almost sure that this is due to the lack of handling of some characters in directory/file names on Windows. 
Which is a shame as the names of indexes should be useable everywhere (hashed for instance)